# Check Captions of Buttons Before Filling Caption of Button without Caption

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, I am trying to check captions of all buttons in a sheet before filling an additional button caption.

I am trying to click the command button named `btn_PTE_Li` and have the first button with an empty caption (out of the 15 command buttons in the sheet) to be filled with "Li" (the Caption of the clicked button). Also, upon filling the caption of that botton (eg.: `btn_Element_i`), the text of a text box `tbx_Number_i` (i corresponding to same integer i as `btn_Element_i`) will fill with the text "1".

Additionally, if any button already has the caption "Li" then another no other button should be filled with an additional caption "Li".

I would like to have this code as general as possible so I can use it for multiple buttons and not just command button `btn_PTE_Li`. It would be nice to have the code refer to the caption of the button clicked to fill the caption of `btn_Element_i`. This way for button `btn_PTE_He`, the code containing "Li" won't need to be changed to "He".

Below is a tentative code that I am currently using to complete this task for 3 buttons `btn_Element_1`, `btn_Element_2`, and `btn_Element_3`:

```
Private Sub btn_PTE_Li_Click()
Me.btn_PTE_Li.BackColor = &H80000010
    If Me.btn_Element_1.Caption = "" Then
        Me.btn_Element_1.Caption = "Li"
        Me.tbx_Number_1.Text = "1"
    ElseIf Me.btn_Element_2.Caption = "" And Me.btn_Element_1.Caption <> "Li" Then
        Me.btn_Element_2.Caption = "Li"
        Me.tbx_Number_2.Text = "1"
    ElseIf Me.btn_Element_3.Caption = "" And Me.btn_Element_1.Caption <> "Li" And Me.btn_Element_2.Caption <> "Li" Then
        Me.btn_Element_3.Caption = "Li"
        Me.tbx_Number_3.Text = "1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping that I correctly understood your question and that you are using **ActiveX controls**, here is what I would suggest if you want it to be general:

Create a class module, name it **MyButtonClass** and paste the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents btControl As MSForms.CommandButton

Private controlName As String

Public Sub btControl_Click()

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    If Left(btControl.Name, 7) = "btn_PTE" Then
        Dim btl As Variant
        btControl.BackColor = &H80000010
        'Check if another button has the same caption
        For Each btl In btCollectionElement
            If TypeName(btl) = "CommandButton" And btl.Caption = btControl.Caption Then Exit Sub
        Next btl

        'Fill caption of the first button with empty caption
        For Each btl In btCollectionElement
            If TypeName(btl) = "CommandButton" And btl.Caption = "" Then
                btl.Caption = btControl.Caption
                Exit For
            End If
        Next btl
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub Attach(newBT As MSForms.CommandButton, newName As String)
    Set btControl = newBT
    controlName = newName
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    controlName = ""
End Sub
```

Then paste the following in a **regular code module**:

```
Option Explicit

Public groupClickCount As Integer
Public btCollection As Collection
Public btCollectionElement As Collection


Public Sub SetUpControlsOnce()
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Set MySheet = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim thisBT As MyButtonClass
    Dim btl As OLEObject
    Dim btControl As MSForms.CommandButton

    If btCollection Is Nothing Then
        Set btCollection = New Collection
    End If

    If btCollectionElement Is Nothing Then
        Set btCollectionElement = New Collection
    End If

    For Each btl In MySheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(btl.Object) = "CommandButton" And Left(btl.Name, 11) = "btn_Element" Then
            '--- this is an ActiveX CheckBox
            Set thisBT = New MyButtonClass
            thisBT.Attach btl.Object, btl.Name
            btCollection.Add thisBT
            btCollectionElement.Add btl.Object
        End If
    Next btl

End Sub

Sub Clear_all_Element_Buttons_Captions()

    Dim btl As Variant
    For Each btl In btCollectionElement
        If TypeName(btl) = "CommandButton" Then
            btl.Caption = ""
        End If
    Next btl

End Sub
```

And you could also add the following to the **ThisWorkbook** Module to make sure that the setup macro runs on opening:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call SetUpControlsOnce
End Sub
```

Notice that the code is using the name of the buttons to distinguish between the types of buttons (those that edit other buttons' caption and those who don't), but there could be other ways to do that. If you find that it takes too long to name properly all you buttons, you could always write a macro that create the buttons and rename them for you (I would suggest having a look at the *record macro* tool to get some insights).

Make sure to change Sheet1 to the apporpriate name of the sheet (both in module and class module).

And for the **textbox** part of your question, you could go for something like this in the btControl_Click macro:

```
Dim Counter as integer
'Fill caption of the first button with empty caption
    For Each btl In btCollectionElement
        Counter = Counter + 1
        If TypeName(btl) = "CommandButton" And btl.Caption = "" Then
            btl.Caption = btControl.Caption
            MySheet.Item("Textbox " & Counter).TextFrame2.TextRange = "1"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btl
```

Comment: Yes! That did what I wanted with some tweaking. I made an additional collection for btCollectionPTE

Comment: @Code123 Great! I'm glad this helped you. I've now added a suggestion to tackle the textbox part.